# ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT no longer overrides DOTNET_ENVIRONMENT?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, environment-variables, .net-7.0

According to the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/environments?view=aspnetcore-7.0), `ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT` is suppose to override the `DOTNET_ENVIRONMENT` environment variable. So, I've went ahead and added a `DOTNET_ENVIRONMENT` entry set to `Development` on my machine's system environment variables.

On one of my projects, I had to create a new custom profile which should only be used when my app uses Kestrel (ex.: run from within VS). In order for my custom profile to be picked up, I've added the following section to one of the profiles:

```
"profiles": {
      "Grm.ClientManagementSite.Wasm.Server": {
        "commandName": "Project",
        "dotnetRunMessages": true,
        "launchBrowser": true,
        "inspectUri": "{wsProtocol}://{url.hostname}:{url.port}/_framework/debug/ws-proxy?browser={browserInspectUri}",
        "applicationUrl": "https://localhost:7126;http://localhost:5126",
        "environmentVariables": {
          "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Local"
        }
      },
...
}
```

I've noticed that whenever I run this profile, the environment is always set up as `Development` (which is defined by the global system entry I've added to the machine's system environment variables).

I've also noticed that if I use the `DOTNET_ENVIRONMENT` variable, then my custom profile will get picked up. I'm almost positive that my previous setting (using `ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT` for overriding the profile on the `lauchSettings.json`) was working when I've created this project. Does anyone know it this is known issue with .NET 7.0?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, starting .NET 7 Preview 3 when using `WebApplicationBuilder` `DOTNET_` varaibles have higher priority than `ASPNETCORE_` ones. See this [github issue](https://github.com/aspnet/Announcements/issues/498) or [this breaking change article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/compatibility/aspnet-core/7.0/environment-variable-precedence).

**UPD**
JIC:

- Created an [issue](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/issues/46325) in ASP.NET Core repo
- Created [PR](https://github.com/dotnet/AspNetCore.Docs/pull/28235) to docs.